# jQuery cache variable naming when multiple word

Tags: jquery, naming-conventions

I know that it is good to name like this:

```
var $number = $('#number');
```

But if there are more than one word like this:

```
$('#number_of_ship');
```

Which one do you think is better `$number_of_ship` or `$numberOfShip`?

It's bad idea to name the id or class in Camel Case because it's case insensitive, so I don't want to name the id like `#numberOfShip`, but I use Camel Case in JavaScript code.

It could be trivial thing, but it bothers me every time.

Comment: I prefer using underscore_case, since, in my opinion, 1) camelCase makes some parts of variable name more important than others, and 2) underscore_case is more readable.

But anyway, please check this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/naming-conventions-camelcase-versus-underscore-case-what-are-your-thoughts-abo (Be sure to read not only the accepted answer, but also the answer with the most votes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressive names are so important. Readability, Maintainability.
Use Camel casing. Its the way to go.
If it bothers you try to get used to it.
See the benefits.